# Generating a String which matches given regex using random-Method of GENEREX

Tags: java, string, intellij-14

I am trying to generate a String which matches a given Regex using the random-Method of GENEREX.

**Target**: as defined in the random Method -> random(min, max), the String is supposed to have between a given min- and max-amount of characters.

**Problem**: the output is matching the defined regex BUT it contains only one character. So it doesn´t consider the defined min and max of the random-Method.

**Code in question**

```
generex= new Generex("[a-zA-Z]");
String output = generex.random(4,15);
```

Value of output at the moment: "P" (f.E.)

Im **Expecting** something like **output**: "WorksFine"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your Regex. It currently is "[a-zA-Z]". So it is only one character. If you want multiple letters you need to add a "+". So it should be:

`generex= new Generex("[a-zA-Z]+");`

Comment: That was it. Thank you Aerith!